# Issues with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I have been struggling with Intents a little but I keep getting an error in this code.I keep getting a FATAL EXCEPTION..

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bac1.problemcodereference/com.example.bac1.problemcodereference.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

Code of my project:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable    {
    private String cPcode;
    Button help , sub;
    EditText codetext;
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);



        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = codetext.getText().toString();
                MainActivity onew = new MainActivity();
                onew.setcPcode(text);
                intent.putExtra("stuff",onew);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });}
```

Answer (score 2):

At this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
```

your activity is not completely constructed so use this call after or inside `oncreate` function   because `this` mean `context` which will be `null` hence the exception

So it will be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable    {
private String cPcode;
Button help , sub;
EditText codetext;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);



    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = codetext.getText().toString();
            MainActivity onew = new MainActivity();
            onew.setcPcode(text);
            intent.putExtra("stuff",onew);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}
```

and another problem is you why you are passing a new object of `mainActivity` so better option is create a separate POJO class and use it to store your data